# mysql_query return an error, but not in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It's really not my first SQL query;), but ...!, I've a weird error : 
I am doing an import from a CSV file into my db, and **the query returns an error with mysql_query**, and **in phpmyadmin, if I copy/paste the query, all is ok**.

```
$result = mysql_query ($ sql);
echo $ sql. "=>". $result. ','. Mysql_error ($this-> cnx). '<br> cnx ='. $this-> cnx. '<br>';
```

In the echo :

```
INSERT INTO tiny_url (`id`, `url`, `tiny_url`, `page_rank`, `link_name`, `destination_url`, `anchor`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, "111", "222", 3, "444", "555", 1,1)
=>, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual That corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
'At line 3
cnx = Resource id # 27
```

and if I do that : it works:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tiny_url (`id`, `url`, `tiny_url`, `page_rank`, `link_name`, `destination_url`, `anchor`, `active `) VALUES (NULL," 111 "," 222 ", 3," 444 "," 555 ", 1,1) ';

$result = mysql_query ($sql);
echo $sql. "=>". $result. ','. mysql_error($this-> cnx). '<br> cnx ='. $this-> cnx. '<br>';
```

Can U help me please ?

Fab

Comment: please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Can you show the CREATE TABLE for your table?

Comment: Can you share the code that involves $this->cnx?  It looks like you are trying to include an object or resource instead of a number?

Comment: Is there any reason you have spaces around your integers in your `INSERT`? `...VALUES (NULL," 111 "," 222 "...`

Answer (score 1):

Your columns is called `active` (followed by a space).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem : In my code, i've added this

```
$sql .= ")<br>";
```

Of course, no html code is allowed in a query.. of course.

Et voila... :(

Fab

Comment: According to this - the second query should have failed.

Comment: Thanks everyone your for all your help, but i've found my problem... it was a silly error... :(